# YARD Cucumber leaves comments in ouput documentation

Tags: ruby, cucumber, yard

In order to localize my Gherkin scripts, I added `#language:ru` comment at the very top of each .feature file and started using localized names for steps and scenarios.

However, this comments lingers(and it is visible right under feature name) in resulting html document after using yard-cucumber plugin to document my scripts. It also adds lines like `features/category_info.feature:3` after each Background/Scenario block. Is it some osrt of debugging mode? I create documentation using "yardoc -c" command, yard-cucumber plugin is autoloaded.

Am I missing something? How do I make yard omit these artifacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, these artifacts appear only when using `yard server --reload`, generated HTML files don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run cucumber with -q to quiet the output regarding the feature/step/line number information.

I don't think you can get rid of the language comment.